# How to integrate elasticSearch with a database and Spring boot

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'm working on a project where we expose a set of APIs using Spring boot and H2 database for development profile and PgSQL for production.

We want to enhance our resources endpoints with a filtering mechanism based on fields, so that we can access something like: ***localhost:8080/api/users?firstName=Jhon&company.job=developer***

We tried to use jpa specification but we were blocked by some limitations like: enumerations, nested element ... So we decided to use ElasticSearch.

All the articles found on the net treat the scenario where we use ElasticSearch as a storage system in the first place and not only an index search engine that can be integrated with a datasource. If anyone can guide me to an implementation on how I can link elasticSearch with a database using Spring boot, it'll be great. Thanks

Comment: Explain what you mean by link ElasticSearch with a database.

Comment: Perhaps Jhipster will do the job

Comment: Why not use save to your ES indices when you save your models in Spring?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli If I understood correctly, with elasticsearch we can index documents or tables in database, so that we can have advanced search mechanism. Since I don't want to waste my time on implementing JPA specifications for nested elements (Join between tables), I want to index my data tables as flat Json object, and use QueryDSL (elasticsearch syntax) to make advanced research based on the param of the URL that I will provide.

Comment: @ryanlutgen Well It'll be great this way I will have a good sync between my Database data and ES, but how can I setup the config to make them both work? Should I create two repositories by domain model (one for JPA and one for ES)?

Comment: @Habchi that would be a good starting point I think.  If you can handle the tying of it all together in the model layer and trigger saves on both, it means that you should be able to be database service agnostic, i.e. be able to switch between H2, PgSQL, Oracle, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a 3rd party server / service just because you would like to query resources like `....?firstName=Jhon&company.job=developer` doesn't seem right.

You would now have (or someone else) to take care of provisioning a cluster of ES nodes, patching, upgrading, performance, monitoring, etc.. and indexing the data stored in the RDBMS.

If you need a text-based search engine, then, yes, you would have to evaluate between Solr, ES and others, but just to have a fancy query filter / query criteria implementation shouldn't justify the inclusion of ES or similar.

Comment: We couldn't find any library to do the job and we do not have time to implement it ourselves so ES was our last solution for such need :/

Comment: Realize that in order to prevent writing a query criteria / filter now you would have to write an indexer, reading batches from a RDBMS and storing them in ES, you would now have to deal with maybe service degradation in ES due to excessive writes (whenever data is changed in DB), security, etc. It might feel this is faster now, but it most-likely will bite you in the future.
Have you taken a look at `spring-data-rest`?